# My jQuery ajax doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, jquery

Just started to learn jQuery ajax today, followed what tutorial said but it did not work.

`HelloWorld` is the method name, but it seems not be recognized as a method name but a page name based on the error message.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //alert("hello world");
    $('.ordernumber').on('click', function () {
        var orderNum = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./OrderDetail.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
                // Do interesting things here.
            }
        });
        //alert($(this).text());

    });
});
```

**OrderDetail.asmx.vb**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web.Services

Public Class OrderDetail
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function

End Class
```

Error Message:

```
POST http://localhost:64616/OrderDetail.asmx/HelloWorld 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: `Internal Server Error` not jQuery fault.

Comment: Hi, please try to run it in IE, from there in Developer Tools you will be able to know what is the error. If its a Internal server error. Then there might be a coding typo in the page you are accessing (OrderDetail) The jQuery is running exactly fine!

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan IE is **NOT** required to debug ajax

Comment: but it is helpfull in finding what is the request type and where the error is. I mentioned that check for the ajax request. Not what request is handling

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add `<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()>` to your class;

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
Public Class OrderDetails
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    '' rest of your code

End Class
```

Also to return Json you need to decorate your methods with;

```
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
```

**Update**

When creating a fresh ASMX Web Service, the default code states;

```
' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
```

Comment: Why? Is it a VB thing?

Comment: It is a .Net thing. In c# it would be the same but `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`

Comment: @TimBJames I added them now. but it returns [object Object] Instead of "Hello World"

Comment: @Quentin Yeah it will be return a Json Object. Usually a .Net ASMX WebService will return something like `{ d: { [other Json] } }`. If you run the code in Google Chrome, and change `alert(msg);` to `console.log(msg)`, then open up the Developer Console, you will see the JSON object returned.

Comment: @TimBJames Thanks. Make much sense!

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting a JSON back, but an asmx webservice returns a XML instead you need to add

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>_
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
 Return "Hello World"
End Function
```

[The link for more explanaiton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.responseformat.aspx)